# Accidentally included special characters in username when adding user

Tags: useradd

I was trying to add a user called `joebloggs` and accidentally hit other keys as I pressed enter:

```
useradd -u 12345 joebloggs$*
```

(on French keyboards the `$` and `*` keys are next to Enter)

doing a cat of /etc/passwd doesn't show anything nasty:

```
joebloggs:x:12345:12345::/home/joebloggs:/bin/bash
```

Is there anything else I should be aware of or checking for?

Comment: ...and you an login properly using `"joebloggs"`?

Comment: Yes I can log in correctly

Answer (score 9):

Everything should be OK, since when you run this from a command-line, `$*` expanded to nothing (i.e. the `useradd` program received just `-u 12345 joebloggs`).